# How to calculate separate binary accuracy metric for each label in a multi-label classification in Keras?

Tags: keras, accuracy, multilabel-classification, metric

I'm stuck with this:

```
def multilabel_binary_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return [K.equal(y_true[:,n], K.round(y_pred[:,n])) for n in range(y_pred.shape[1])]
```

But it returns only a number similar to the binary accuracy metric from Keras.